PyCharm Professional 2024.1 - Can't associate venv with project on lockdown laptop
I recently upgraded to PyCharm Professional on a 'locked down' Windows laptop and I can't associate the virtual environment with the project?
I can find the checkbox for this function under File -> Settings - Project ** -> Python Interpreter -> Click the dropdown and select 'Show All'.
From there I can see, and click, the checkbox for 'Associate this virtual environment with the current project'. I can then click Apply and then click Ok, no error is displayed BUT that setting is not saved!

I have tried removing and recreating the virtual environment no luck.
So, are there any directories under the AppData/Local that I can safely delete to reset the PyCharm some 'under the hood' Pycharm settings? Something like
AppData\Local\JetBrains\PyCharm2024.1
Can I safely delete the above directory, will PyCharm rebuild everything it needs when it starts?

I see that this issue is at least 4 month old already. You can track it here
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-71760/Python-venv-cannot-be-associated-with-only-one-project
